# "Peer-Review": Synonyme, Desubstantivierungen, Konjugationen und Deklinationen

Tags: translation, verb, noun, declension, conjugation

Heißt es "die peer-reviewte Quelle"? Ich finde, es hört sich komisch an. Ich suche nach:

- Synonymen (wie z. B. Kreuzgutachten)
- Verb**en**
- Konjugation der Verben
- Deklinationen der Substantive

Comment: Ja, "peer-reviewte" ist korrekt, liest sich auch in Ordnung, sieht nur auf den ersten Blick etwas komisch aus ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### *Wissenschaft*

Zumindest in meinem wissenschaftlichen Umfeld wird meist implizit davon ausgegangen, dass *wissenschaftliche Veröffentlichungen, wissenschaftliche Zeitschriften* o. Ä. sich durch den Peer-Review-Prozess von normalen Veröffentlichungen und Zeitschriften abgrenzen. Im Vergleich zum englischen Sprachgebrauch werden Peer-Reviews deutlich seltener explizit erwähnt.

#### *Review*

Soll das Peer-Review explizit erwähnt werden und von anderen Gutachten abgegrenzt werden, wird zumindest in meinem wissenschaftlichen Umfeld umgangssprachlich *Review* oder *Peer-Review* (Substantiv) bzw. *reviewen* (Verb), selten auch *peerreviewen* genutzt, also z. B.:

> Das Paper ist gerade im Review.
> Das Paper ist gerade im Peer-Review.
>
> Der Peer-Review-Prozess dauerte drei Monate.
>
> Die reviewte Quelle.
> Die gereviewte Quelle.
> Die peerreviewte Quelle.
> Die gepeerreviewte Quelle.
>
> Ich habe das Paper reviewt.
> Ich habe das Paper gereviewt.
> Ich habe das Paper peerreviewt.
> Ich habe das Paper gepeerreviewt.

Dabei ist *Review**s*** der Genitiv Singular sowie der Plural (alle Fälle) von *Review*; alle anderen Formen sind *Review*.

*Reviewen* und *peerreviewen* werden wie regelmäßige (starke) Verben konjugiert; die Verwendung der Vorsilbe *ge* zur Bildung des Partizips ist uneinheitlich. Gegen die Verwendung von *ge* spricht, dass man *re* parallel zu den Vorsilben *be* oder *er* ansehen kann, welche eine Partizipbildung ohne *ge* verursachen. Mir sind keine anderen Verben bekannt, deren Partizipbildung man hier als Vorbild heranziehen könnte. Zwar bilden Verben wie *reformieren* oder *reklamieren* ihr Partizip auch ohne *ge*, dies ist aber bereits dadurch gegeben, dass sie auf *ieren* enden. Andere im Deutschen verwendete Verben, die mit der Vorsilbe *re* beginnen und nicht auf *ieren* enden, sind mir nicht bekannt.

#### *Gutachten*

Im offiziellen Kontext kenne ich nur *Gutachten* bzw. *begutachten.* Zum Beispiel redet die Promotionsordnung meiner Fakultät von *begutachteten Veröffentlichungen*, womit ziemlich sicher *peer-reviewed publications* gemeint sind. Einziger Nachteil ist, dass es andere Arten von Gutachten gibt, was missverstanden bzw. ausgenutzt werden kann.

Diese Begriffe sind auch im normalen Sprachgebrauch verbreitet.

Comment: _recyclen_ bildet sein Partizip i.d.R. auch ohne _ge-_ (hat aber eine Silbe mehr, was das vielleicht erleichtert).

Answer (score 2):

Bei uns am naturwissenschaftlichen Institut wird *peer-reviewte Quellen* (konjugiert wie *überprüfen*), *Quellen mit Peer-Review* oder *Peer-Review-Quelle* (siehe auch [Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/peer-reviewed+journals.html?cw=336)) verwendet. Als Verb sind *ein Review schreiben* oder *ein Review bearbeiten* verbreitet. Prinzipiell ginge auch *ein Gutachten schreiben*, das wird aber nur für die Gutachten (Bewertungen) von Bachlor-/Master-/Doktorarbeiten genutzt, nicht für Paper (Artikel).

Das deutsche Synonym *Kreuzgutachten* habe ich im wissenschaftlichen Alltag noch nie verwendet oder gehört. Ich würde daher die Verwendung von *Peer-Review* empfehlen (vgl. [deutscher Wikiartikel zu Peer-Review](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-Review)).

Answer (score 0):

Eventuell ist es hier sinnvoller mit Relativsätzen zu arbeiten, anstatt Peer-Review als Adjektiv zu nutzen.

> Quellen, die Peer-Reviews unterzogen wurden

oder

> durch Peer-Reviews geprüfte/begutachtete Quellen

Um die eigentliche Frage zu beantworten, wären *kollegenkontrolliert* oder auch *von anderen Wissenschaflern begutachtet* gebräuchlich (wenn auch afaik tendenziell wenig).